# Can't get azure ad authorization flow to trigger in my ionic-framework app

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, ionic-framework, adal

I am trying to get Azure Active Directory Authentication on my application.

I have followed instructions for setting up my Azure directory application using the [Windows documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-cordova)

I have also created the application and added the code found in the [Ionicframework documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ms-adal/)

Html element calling login():

```
 <button ion-button (click)="login()">Login</button>
```

My code: *home.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MSAdal, AuthenticationContext, AuthenticationResult } from '@ionic-native/ms-adal';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  ready = false;

  authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
  redirectUri = "http://IonicAuthenticationTest";
  resourceUri = "https://graph.windows.net";
  clientId = "Left out application id for security reasons";
  graphApiVersion = "2013-11-08";
  authContext : AuthenticationContext;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private msAdal: MSAdal, private tc: ToastController) {
    this.authContext = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext(this.authority);

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.ready = true;
  }

  login() {
    this.authContext.acquireTokenAsync(this.resourceUri, this.clientId, this.redirectUri)
    .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
      console.log('Token is' , authResponse.accessToken);
      console.log('Token will expire on', authResponse.expiresOn);
    })
    .catch((e: any) => console.log('Authentication failed', e));
  }

}
```

I build and test my application(s) using ionic pro. Basically when I click the login button, nothing is happening, no browser is opening or nothing. Just goes straight to the 'catch' with an undefined error...

I am missing something, but what?

Thanks for your help men and women!

Comment: My AuthorizationContext stays undefined I think: 
This is a what i get when I log authContext before acquring the token:

`[Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'authority' of undefined at AuthenticationContext.get [as authority]`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test from browser neither Ionic View/Ionic Pro. You need to test from emulator or real device.